# Form validation and storing with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

I have a task in which I am required to build a very simple website in which the user is prompted to fill a form and submit it. After that, a validation check will be made and a message of success will be presented to him (maybe in a different page). The fields of the table in which the form's inputs are going to be stored are the following:

```
TABLE inquiries (
inquiry_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
submit_date DATETIME,
first_name VARCHAR(35),
last_name VARCHAR(35),
address VARCHAR(255),
postcode VARCHAR(8),
email VARCHAR(254),
phone VARCHAR(11),
wedding_date DATE,
wedding_location VARCHAR(50),
special_req TEXT
);
```

So, basically my form includes everything from above, but inquiry_id and submit_date.

Initially, I validate my form by putting in my HTML code the following

```
<form name = "Order Form" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = "post">
```

and in a php script before I make all the ckecks. This works fine.

My main problem is in storing these inputs in the given DB. Upon now, I've tried this:

a)Before closing the form, I have this php script:

```
        $connection=mysqli_connect("serverName","username","password","DB");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
       date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
//I use a datepicker with the format mm/dd/yyy, but I want the format yyyy/mm/dd TIMESTAMP
       $currentDate = date('Y/m/d h:i:s a', time());
       $date = date('Y-m-d');
       mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO inquiries 
        (submit_date, first_name, last_name, address,    postcode, email, phone,  wedding_date,     wedding_location, special_req)
        VALUES
        ('$currentDate', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$street', '$postcode', '$email',  '$mobileNumber', '$date', '$city', '$comments')");
       mysqli_close($connection);
```

This doesn't work...

b) I created a new php file and named it "DBStore.php" in order to call it in the previous form, so now action="DBStore.php". Unfortunately, I don't have access to the DB to see if the inputs are stored properly, but the only thing I get is a blank page.

I want to combine both the validation and the store in one file, if it's possible.

How can I do the previous (both validation and storing, with a presentation of a proper message)?

I would prefer to keep in both cases php coding.

The code for the validation is:

```
<?php //code retrieved and customized from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required
              // define variables and set to empty values
            $firstNameError = $lastNameError = $streetError = $cityError = $postcodeError = $emailError = $mobileNumberError = $dateError = "";
            $firstName = $lastName = $street = $city = $postcode = $email = $mobileNumber = $date = "";
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
            {
                if (empty($_POST["firstName"]))
                {$firstNameError = "Please fill this field";}
                else
                {
                    $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName))
                    {
                        $firstNameError = "Please use only letters and white spaces"; 
                    }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["lastName"]))
                {$lastNameError = "Please fill this field";}
                else
                {
                    $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName))
                    {
                        $lastNameError = "Please use only letters and white spaces"; 
                    }
                }   
                if (empty($_POST["street"]))
                {$streetError = "Please fill this field";}
                else 
                {
                    // check if street address syntax is valid
                    $street = test_input($_POST["street"]);
                    if(!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $street)){
                        $streetError = "Please use only letters, numbers and whitespaces";
                    }
                }   
                if (empty($_POST["city"]))
                {$cityError = "Please fill this field";}
                else
                {
                    // check if city syntax is valid
                    $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city))
                    {
                        $cityError = "Please use only letters and whitespaces"; 
                    }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["postcode"]))
                {$postcodeError = "Please fill this field";}
                else 
                {
                    //check if postcode syntax is valid
                    $postcode = test_input($_POST["postcode"]);
                    if(!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*$/', $postcode)){
                        $postcodeError = "Please use only letters, numbers and whitespace";
                    }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["email"]))
                {$emailError = "Please fill this field";}
                else
                {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
                    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
                    {
                        $emailError = "Please rewrite your email address in the format a@b.code"; 
                    }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["mobileNumber"]))
                {$mobileNumberError = "Please fill this field";}
                else 
                {
                    $mobileNumber = test_input($_POST["mobileNumber"]);
                    // check if mobile number syntax is valid
                 if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/',$mobileNumber))
                    {
                    $mobileNumberError = "Please write only numbers";
                    }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["date"]))
                {$dateError = "Please fill this field";}
            //echo "I'm here";
            //exit();   
        }   
        function test_input($data)
        {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
    ?>
```

The full HTML form is this:

```
<form name = "Order Form" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = "post">--></form>
                <!--<form name = "Order Form" action = "DBStore.php" method = "post">-->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>First name: </td>
                        <!--Printing the field values after the validation, customization made based on http://www.w3resource.com/php/form/php-form-validation.php --> 
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "firstName" value = "<?php echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left"><span class="error"><?php echo $firstNameError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>Last name: </td> 
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "lastName" value = "<?php echo $_POST['lastName']; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left"><span class="error"><?php echo $lastNameError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>Address: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "street" value = "<?php echo $_POST['street']; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left"><span class="error"><?php echo $streetError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>Postcode: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "postcode" value = "<?php echo $_POST['postcode']; ?>"/></td>                
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left>"><span class="error"><?php echo $postcodeError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>E-mail: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "email" value = "<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/></td>          
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left>"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>Contact number: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "mobileNumber" value = "<?php echo $_POST['mobileNumber']; ?>"/></td>                
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left"><span class="error"><?php echo $mobileNumberError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">*</span>Wedding date: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "date" id ="date" value = "<?php echo $_POST['date']; ?>"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left"><span class="error"><?php echo $dateError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align = "right"><span class="error">* </span>Wedding location: </td>
                        <td align = "left"><input type = "text" name = "city" value = "<?php echo $_POST['city']; ?>"/></td>            
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align = "left>"><span class="error"><?php echo $cityError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right"> Leave your comments:</td>
                        <td><textarea rows = "7" cols = "30" name = "comments" id = "comments" value = "<?php echo $_POST['comments']; ?>"/></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br>
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit Details" style ="margin-left: 145px;"/>
                <input type = "reset" value = "Clear Form"/>
            </div>
</form>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: 1. Your insert statement is prone to SQL injection. 2. Can you please elaborate "This doesn't work..."?

Comment: You are going to get a blank page because if you are successful, it won't output anything. If you want to use it on the same page then just put the script on the same page

Comment: Its better to not make pages submit to themselves when you can avoid it. It makes code messy to do everything on one page.

Comment: I would try to get access to the database or at least create a script that outputs the entire contents of the database table so that you can verify if it is adding to the DB or not.  And also check mysql errors

Comment: @aarryy: Sorry, the syntax was pretty awful. I meant that if I put the previous block of code in the same script in which I made the validation, nothing happens (basically, only the validation happens...)

Comment: We need to see the validation code, the storage code, and the full form code to help you with this one.

Comment: @IanAnders: I edited my question and posted the validation code. Regarding the storage code, it has been already in the question body at the "a)Before closing the form, I have this php script". Thanks!

Comment: Still need the full form. We need to see the submit button as well as where your PHP is happening. You said you have your storage PHP code "Before closing the form". What does that mean? Before the </form> tag? It would help the see the complete form.

Comment: @IarsAnders: I put the full HTML form.By "Before closing the form", yes I mean the form tag. I tried it that way, but nothing. Then, I tried to create a separate php file which I called it DBStore.php. There I was thinking of opening a connection to DB, making the validation, inserting the data into the DB and closing the connection. So, basically, combine into one file the validation and the storing script. Thanks for continuing on helping! :) Is it now clearer?

Comment: "This doesn't work" is the least possible elaborate hint about an error.